# tracking of fonts in small capital with frenchb from babel+ microtype

Tags: fonts, babel, small-caps, microtype, french

I have a problem in enabling tracking of small caps [whether the font has small caps or not] when I load french babel plus `microtype`.
The problem appears only in my titles for the section and only when those titles have some characters `!, »` and perhaps others.
If I disable the `tracking` from `microtype`, all goes well.

```
LuaTeX error /texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/frenchb.lua:66: attempt to index a nil value. \section{SSS! » !}
```

Here is a extract from the manual of `frenchb`, at page 38, which says that babels tweaks the small caps :

> \bsc: As family names
>   should be written in small capitals and never be hyphenated, we
>   provide a command (its name comes from Boxed Small Caps) to input them
>   easily. Note that this command has changed with version 2 of frenchb:
>   a \kern0pt is used instead of \hbox because \hbox would break
>   microtype’s font expansion; as a (positive?) side effect, composed
>   names (such as Dupont-Durand) can now be hyphenated on explicit
>   hyphens. Usage: Jean~\bsc{Duchemin}.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\bsc}[1]{\leavevmode\begingroup\kern0pt \scshape #1\endgroup}
\ifLaTeXe\else\let\scshape\relax\fi
```

I have no error when `lualatex` compiles with `microtype` without `babel` and I do not have errors when only `babel` is present.
**There is no error with `microtype+babel` **if I do not redefine my section with `\scshape`**.**

I need `polyglossia` because I have other languages with peculiar fonts,. **I have no error when I disable `tracking` in `microtype`, but still keep `babel+polyglossia+microtype`... plus my definition of `\section`**

This is the `tex` file

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}%%


\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{
Ligatures=TeX,
%Mapping=tex-text,
SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic}
}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}



\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{%
\penalty-9999
\@startsection {section}{1}{0em}{0\parskip}{1cm}{%
\centering\rmfamily\bfseries\scshape%
\righthyphenmin=62%
}
}
\makeatother


\usepackage[%
babel=true,
%protrusion=true,
%expansion=true,
%%%%%activate={true,nocompatibility}
%kerning=false,
%spacing=false,
tracking=true,
%factor=1100,
%stretch=40,
%shrink=10
]{microtype}
\SetTracking{encoding={*}, family= *, shape=sc}{33}

\begin{document}

\section{SSS! » !}



\end{document}
```

Comment: It makes no real sense to use `babel` together with `polyglossia`. However, `tracking` doesn't work with `xelatex` and  TeX Gyre Termes has no bold Small Caps.

Comment: With `fontspec`, you can use  a command like this:  `\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}`.